# Storing a string on Android in similar fashion to iOS Keychain

Tags: android

Is there an android service where I can store a string that is similar to iOS Keychain. I'm looking for it to have the following attributes (or at least some of these attributes):

- Survives an app delete/re-install
- Is attached to an "account"
- Is wiped if the phone is wiped

It doesn't need to be ultra secure.

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an android service where I can store a string that is similar to iOS Keychain

No. The closest thing to Keychain is Android's `KeyStore`, and that is for X.509 certificates, not arbitrary strings.

> Survives an app delete/re-install

Android goes to some pain to prevent apps from cluttering up the user's device with stuff that survives an uninstall.